# How can I create a table in an .hpp for a general contract? (Using the CDT)

Tags: table, abi, c++, eosiocpp

**THE STRUCTURE OF MY PROJECT**

I am working in `mycontract.cpp`, which imports `myheader.hpp`

---

**WHAT I WANT**

I want to create a *table* in `myheader.hpp`, for a generic contract, "IN THEORY" as follows:

```
struct [[eosio::table, eosio::contract(_self)]] test {
  ...
}
```

---

**WHAT IS NOT WORKING**

1. `eosio::contract(_self)`, in the WHAT I WANT section, is not a valid code.
2. in what used to be the standard way of defining a table, the table section in the ABI is not generated by the new compiler `eosio-cpp`.

In fact, if I create a *table* like the following:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] test {
  ...
}
```

the code compiles; but, the *table* does **not appear in `mycontract`'s tables section in the ABI**.

---

**WHAT IS WORKING**

If I create a *table* in `myheader.hpp`, for a specific contract, as follows:

```
struct [[eosio::table, eosio::contract("mycontract")]] test {
  ...
}
```

the code compiles; and, the *table* **appears in `mycontract`'s table section in the ABI**.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6015 Could you show how you're typdefing the Multi Index container? It's now like this: `typedef eosio::multi_index< "accounts"_n, account > accounts;` This may also be a good resource to look at: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence

Comment: I am doing like this: `typedef eosio::multi_index<name("test"), test> t_test`. Btw, I will check, thanks for sharing. But I need to define a general table in the .hpp file, .hpp which includes also the table typedef.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are going to achieve.

If you are just trying to reuse the old code in a hurry, I would suggest:

### SOLUTION 1

#### header.hpp

```
struct [[ eosio::table]] test {
  uint64_t prim_key;
  uint64_t timestamp;

  auto primary_key() const { return prim_key; }
};
```

#### one.cpp

```
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT one : public contract {
private:
  #include "../header.hpp"
  typedef multi_index<name("one"), test> test_table;

public:
  using contract::contract;
  ACTION hi(name user) { print_f("Hello % from one", user); }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(one, (hi))
```

If you think it is ugly and want to spend some effort extract an macro, try:

### SOLUTION 2

#### header.hpp

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

struct [[ eosio::table, eosio::contract(__MY__CONTRACT__)]] test {
  uint64_t prim_key;
  uint64_t timestamp;

  auto primary_key() const { return prim_key; }
};
```

#### one.cpp

```
#define __MY__CONTRACT__ "one"
#include "../header.hpp"
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT one : public contract {
  private:
    typedef multi_index<name("one"), test> test_table;

  public:
    using contract::contract;
    ACTION hi(name user) { print_f("Hello % from one", user); }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(one, (hi))
```

The last solution may not fit your needs as you need the table have same name with contract. However, we use it in our own projects so I would like show it here:

### SOLUTION 3

#### header.hpp

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

struct test {
  uint64_t prim_key;
  uint64_t timestamp;

  auto primary_key() const { return prim_key; }
};
```

#### one.cpp

```
#include "../header.hpp"
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT one : public contract {
  private:
    TABLE tableone : test{};
    typedef multi_index<name("one"), test> test_table;

  public:
    using contract::contract;
    ACTION hi(name user) { print_f("Hello % from one", user); }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(one, (hi))
```

### Conclusion

This can be also done by many other macro tricks and you can pick which ever you like.